# Get a word location from a label and hover it with another label c#

Tags: c#

I have a question...i'm trying to hover a specific word from a label with another label, but i don't know how to get the specific word position from the label's text. I would be very happy if you could help me at least, how to get the word location in the label. I have to say that the label Autosize is false, so it could have more than just one line. Thank you!

Comment: Is it really necessary to solve the problem by hiding a word with an another label? A word location depends on many factors (e.g. font size, font style etc).

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application or a web site? Maybe you should try to transform that label into 3 labels, so that word is only in the middle one, and add the hovering logic only over that one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to reference one of the words in one label's .Text property and use it in another label when you hover over the first label.

If you know already what word in the string you want, it's easy.  You can fetch it by the 0-indexed position of the letters, since a string is really just an array of type Char. You can also use String class tricks like .Substring() to fetch the word.

I think the degree of complexity you've added, though, is that (and correct me if I'm wrong) you want the second label to display the specific word over which the mouse is hovering while the mouse is hovering over the first label.  That involves getting the label's coordinates as well as the pointer's, and a rather complex method for determining "what is a word, really?".  If possible, I would split your source label into a label for each word.  This can be done with dynamic labels by inheriting from the Label (or a container, like Panel) class in a custom control and giving it an IEnumerable of Labels as a property.  Doing this, you can assign the OnHover handlers at runtime, and evaluate these events as individual labels rather than having to do the math and hope that a screen resolution change doesn't ruin your day.